# spyon doesn't work with nested function in a non angularjs environment

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine, spyon

I'm having a problem to spyon a function that is called from another function in my javascript module (no angularJS)

this is the javascript module:

```
var Utils = function () {

function getFunction1(value1) {
    var value2 = getFunction2();

    return value1 + value2;
};

function getFunction2() {

    return 10;
};

return {
    getFunction1: getFunction1,
    getFunction2: getFunction2
};
};
```

my test is:

```
describe('test spyon', function () {

var myApp = new Utils();
it('test spyOn', function () {

    spyOn(myApp, 'getFunction2').and.returnValue(2);

    // call a function under test and assert
    expect(myApp.getFunction1(1)).toBe(3);
});
});
```

I run the command:

```
gradle build karma
```

And the result is:

```
    PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) test spyon test spyOn FAILED
Expected 11 to be 3.
Error: Expected 11 to be 3.
    at X:/projects/ETRANS-CALCULATOR/branches/ONS128-ONS129-LifeIPCalculators/Common/src/test/webapp/unit/utilsSpec.js:30
    at X:/projects/ETRANS-CALCULATOR/branches/ONS128-ONS129-LifeIPCalculators/Common/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js:126
    at X:/projects/ETRANS-CALCULATOR/branches/ONS128-ONS129-LifeIPCalculators/Common/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:171
    at http://localhost:9876/karma.js:182
    at http://localhost:9876/context.html:67
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.946 secs / 0.002 secs)
:Common:karma FAILED
```

If I do the same test in an AngularJS controller it will work using $scope instead of myApp

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getFunction2` referenced in `getFunction1` is the scoped function `getFunction2`, not myApp's instance of `getFunction2`. The spy is spying on the instance's `getFunction2` though.

To fix this, you should use `this.getFunction2` in `getFunction1` rather than `getFunction2`.

i.e.

```
function getFunction1(value1) {
    var value2 = this.getFunction2();

    return value1 + value2;
};
```

Comment: Cool, this worked, not a deal that I have to change all the call to the nested function adding this if i want to mock them with Jasmine and spyOn. There is a better way to do it? and why is I use $scope it works?

Comment: Could you show the code where you use $scope and it works?

Comment: I have just released that in AngularJS I always use the "$scope" that does exactly what "this" does:  $scope.function1 call $scope.function2